# How to print only the last element of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to print the last element of my array. The code can be seen below:

```
double [] results = new double[21];
double t = 9600;

for(int y = 0; y < 21; y++) {

    results[y] = t;
    t *= 1.04;

    System.out.println(results[results.length - 1]);

}
```

However, when I attempt to run this, I get this result:

```
0.0 (printed 20 times in a row)
...
21034.782173120842
```

I do not know why it is printing out 20 zero's, and then the answer I want `(21034.78)`. I thought that by doing `results[results.length - 1]`, only the last element of the array would be printed. I have a suspicion that this has to do with the loop, but I do not know why or how to fix it.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are printing the last index on every iteration of the loop. It will remain it's default value of `0.0` until the last iteration where you set it to a value

Comment: Where do you define `t`? And why not `System.out.println(results[results.length - 1]);` outside the loop?

Comment: What's the point of the array if you are only going to use the last element? Couldn't you just do [this](https://hastebin.com/kitukagezu.cs)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `System.out.println` outside the for loop, or else you will always print 0.0 because the last index of the array isn't filled yet.

```
double [] results = new double[21];
double t = 9600;

for(int y = 0; y < 21; y++) { 
        results[y] = t;
        t *= 1.04;
}

System.out.println(results[results.length - 1]);
```

Output: 21034.782173120842

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the print statement outside the loop..

```
double [] results = new double[21]; double t = 9600;

for(int y = 0; y < 21; y++) {

    results[y] = t;
    t *= 1.04;

}
System.out.println(results[results.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

put your System.out.println , out of loop.

```
for(int y = 0; y < 21; y++) {
     ** YOUR LOGIC **
   }
    System.out.println(results[results.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a slight alteration. Here is one thing that you can do:

```
double [] results = new double[21];
double t = 9600;

for(int y = 0; y < results.length; y++) {


        results[y] = t;
        t *= 1.04;
        System.out.println(results[y]);

    }
```

You can print the current index [y] each time through the loop. Or else you're always printing index 21 which isn't filled yet and will repeatedly print 0 until it is filled. The current iteration of the loop [y] will always be the last index that actually has a value in it, but the last index won't actually be filled with a value until your last iteration through the loop which explains your error here.